# Android VLC launch from HTML, why does the colon get replaced with "%3A" and what can I do?

Tags: android, html, vlc

I'm trying to use:

```
<a href="android-app://org.videolan.vlc/http/my.example.com:8080/test.mp4">OPEN IN VLC</a>
```

But VLC pops up a toast saying:

```
The location http://my.example.com%3A8080/test.mp4 cannot be played.
```

Is there any other way for me to specify the port?

Answer (score 4):

Ended up using:

```
<a href="intent://my.example.com:8080/test.mp4#Intent;scheme=http;package=org.videolan.vlc;end">OPEN IN VLC</a>
```

Comment: I tried following it opens vlc on app store instead of sending the url to already installed vlc for android! do you know what is the problem ?Thanks

Comment: @user1788736 That's because the VLC app is not installed. Try installing it first and then starting the intent.

Answer (score -1):

Use it like this:

```
<a href="vlc://https://example.com/1.mpd" > Open in vlc </a>
```